# JdbcPollingChannelAdapter setUpdateSql - binding parameter wrapped with quotes

Tags: spring-integration

I need to wrap the parameter with quotes in query.

```
=':param'

   JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(...
   adapter.setUpdateSql("..COL =':param'");
   adapter.setUpdateSqlParameterSourceFactory(...)
```

If I add quote parameter is not replaced, if i remove the quotes parameter replaced - but I must have the quotes.

The type of bounded filed is long.

Tried different wrappings.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be with quotes, then the result of `param` evaluation has to be quoted.
Or it looks like it has to be evaluated to `String`, not long as you mention. The query binding doesn't work like you expect. It really has to be a top-level instruction for the query processor to let it to bind the value properly from the template.

See if `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` can help you somehow to evaluate the result of `:param` to expected quoted value: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc

Comment: dirty workaround like sql's specific dialect: `to_char(:param)` solves it but i do not like it

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. Looks like there is just enough to evaluate the `param` into `String` in your code if you don't like that `to_char()`.